# Separate basic auth on front and back end with NGINX

Tags: authentication, nginx, proxy, http-headers

So, i am trying to setup an NGINX reverse proxy with SSL from client to proxy, comms from the proxy to the actual server is http.

To complicate matters i need to use the Basic Auth functionality on NGINX to authenticate the user accessing the site before granting access to the backend server. Additionally the backend server itself requires logging into, these values are hard-coded into the config file for that VHost.

The problem is when both are enabled i can't actually access the server, i am asked to login, repeatedly, and am never able to access the page.

If i disable the auth requirement on the back end have it enabled on the front end, everything works fine and i can login and access the correct page. If i disable the front end auth and enable the backend auth, this gets correctly passed and everything works.

So, i'm guessing this has something to do with the Authorisation info form the front end somehow making it's way to the back end via the proxy, and it's not working as those credentials are not valid.

I have tried clearing the auth headers before resetting them in the VHosts location settings using more_clear_headers, but whilst that seems to allow the initial request to go through, the remaining ones to load the page hit the auth block again and i am asked to login.

Here is my current config for the host
(with specific details replaced with an #), can anyone advise on where i am going wrong here?

Thanks

```
server {

    # SSL configuration
    #
    listen 443;
    listen [::]:443;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/#.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/#.pem;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/#_access.log upstreamlog;
    server_name #.#.co.uk;
    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-Ip $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
            more_clear_headers Authorization;
            proxy_set_header Authorization "Basic #####2V0Om5#####=";
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass http://10.0.1.201:9981;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've also seen this, and have not found a way to use basic auth on both connections when using a reverse proxy. The problem, as you say, is that the authorization header is being overwritten by the backend, and then used by the client to connect to the front end.

Comment: What if send http auth directly through http: `proxy_pass http://user:passs@10.0.1.201:9981;`?

Comment: This just adds the authorization header, leading to the problem indicated in the question

Comment: have you trued `more_set_input_headers "Authorization: Basic #####2V0Om5#####="`, to rewrite the request headers? If it runs after the reverse proxy Auth check it could maybe work.

Comment: Try to add in `location / { auth_basic off; ...}` and not change other lines. From nginx docs: 'auth_basic string | off; Context: http, server, location [...] The special value off allows cancelling the effect of the auth_basic directive inherited from the previous configuration level.'